Suddenly Android App stopped rotating on device rotation (permanent portrait)
Fellow android devs,
I'm developing a Jetpack Compose Native App and recently the app stopped rotating when I rotate the device. The auto rotate is ON. I tried two emulators Pixel 9 and 8 and a physical device with SDK 30. No idea what happened because I can't track any changes related to device rotation.
That's my manifest:
  <application
    android:name=".app.android.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme"
    tools:targetApi="35">

    <activity
        android:name=".app.host.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> <!--adjustNothing is used to deal with imePadding-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

Theme:
 <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

I have "custom splash screen that's why I set the "windowIsTranslucent".
Also, I use the GoogleMap SDK but the rotation is not happening on any screen.
N.B. - I'm not aiming to force portrait and also the auto rotate works across the device.

I believe the issue is caused by setting android:windowIsTranslucent to true in the theme, which can prevent the system from handling screen orientation changes properly.

If the translucent window is only needed for the splash screen, u can apply this feature to the splash screen activity by creating a seperate theme.

Let me try @Faruk. But I need the windowIsTranslucent otherwise there will a double stack of splash screens. I can't use the default splash as it requires a rounded image and I want to place a logo.

If it works you can create a new theme that will be used only for splash. It's pretty simple

Basically the problem is the android:windowIsTranslucent. More information here: android:@Theme.Translucent Locks orientation to Portrait?
To fix that either add android:screenOrientation="sensor" to the activity (only one in compose app) or find a different way to create a custom splash screen.
